# Stretching Mesh When Bevelling

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, bezier-curves, edit-mode

I won't waste your time on irrelevancies.

I am trying to bevel along the edges of this heart.
However, every time I try and do so the edge clips through in an unpredictable course: [image]

I assumed the issue was along the radical line of the two arcs so I took the liberty of merging the cleavage to a single point and removing the doubles, additionally creating a wider intersecting arc. This ajustment, however, was frustratingly ineffectual.

[Here is the file.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/prq34kk1p5k3vkp/Heart.blend?dl=0)

Thank you for sparing your time to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you eneable **Backface Culling** from the Properties panel you will see that half or your heart has its face normals pointing inwards.
Also the edges you are trying to bevel have duplicted Vertices.

To fix your beveling you need to do as M.ardito suggested:
With all of the heart selected **Recalculate Normals** and **Remove Doubles**
If you now select that edge and use the Bevel tool it will look alot better, but.... if you look closely there is still a little problem area.
[image]

To correct that anomalie Patdog has given the solution,

Select only the top faces of the heart and using the **Insert** tool (keyboard shortcut key **I** ), insert a inner edge loop on those faces.

Now you can go back to using the Bevel tool and it should bevel ok.
The extra edge loop on the top face can now be deleted ( **X** > **Edge Loops** )

[image]

Comment: What is the shortcut for the mesh mode selection?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Bevel is guided along the mesh that exists. When the mesh points to one point that can cause clashes as things pile up. It's not bad practice to give the geometry some room to move & slide down. Also with your form being symmetrical it is maybe a good opportunity to take advantage of the mirror settings.

The top heart has one big Ngon with edges selected. The bottom heart is ideal with a mesh loop to scale along....

[image: Bevel]

Comment: Ah! I see. This was very helpful in understanding this tool. Thank you for explaining it to me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this

- removed doubles
- recalculated face normals
- started beveling
- pressed <kbd>C</kbd> during bevel (to set clamp overlap ON)
- used mousewheel to raise segments

[image]

but I don't know if this helps you, as the beveling is limited in this way... and I don't know which shape were you trying to get...

Comment: Sorry I was not clear. I was hoping to bevel furthur down to the edge loop. Though this was still very helpful in understanding the mechanics of Blender. Thank you.